# dataframe groupby or slice based on conditions

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A','A','A','B','B','A','B','B','B','B','A','A','A','A'],
                       'ID2':[1,2,3,1,1,1,6,7,1,2,2,5,6,1]})
df_test
```

[image: df_test]

The result dataframe would be like this ('ID1' was group/slice by the value, for example, if A was repeated at least 2 times, these 2 rows will be treated as a group and calculate the mean of ID2. it's similar to 'B', but only if 'B' repeat at least 3 times):

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'ID1':['A1','B1','A2'],
                       'mean_ID2':[2,4,3.5]})
df_result
```

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you need

Comment: Do you have only 'A' and 'B' in your column ID1? if no, do you have a structure that say you want to consider at least 2 following A, 3 following B, ...

Comment: Do you mean consecutive groups of As and Bs? And what should happen with the As and Bs that do not satisfy the condition, are they not included in the resulting database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use run length encoding to figure out the rows to keep based on number of elements in consecutive runs. in the next step, group by consecutive runs again and take mean.

```
import pdrle
r = pdrle.encode(df_test.ID1)
r["chk"] = ((r.vals == "A") & (r.runs >=2)) | ((r.vals == "B") & (r.runs >= 3))
df2 = df_test[pdrle.decode(r.chk, r.runs)]
df2.groupby(pdrle.get_id(df2.ID1)).agg({"ID1": "first", "ID2": "mean"})
#     ID1     ID2
# ID1
# 0     A     2.0
# 1     B     4.0
# 2     A     3.5
```